# JavaFX, shortcuts, mnemonic, how to avoid beeping

Tags: java, audio, javafx, shortcut, beep

I have a question regarding JavaFX 2.2: every time a mnemonic key is pressed (for example Alt-A, Alt-B, etc.) the JavaFX is beeping (Windows default system sound is played). It doesn't matter if the mnemonic is valid or not for current components of the scene. If the mnemomic is valid (for example for Button or Label) the JavaFX is doing the corresponding action (Button is pressed or Label change the focus) but it also beeps suggesting that user have done an invalid action. I can observe it only for Alt-Key's, it doesn't matter if they are used as mnemonic or accelerator, Ctrl-Keys works ok. How to avoid the beeps for Alt-Key's?
Is there a possibility to avoid beeps by valid action?
Should I handle the events in some special way to consume them fully?
Is there a possibility to mute the whole application or scene or stage?
 

Regards,
Annie

Comment: Could it be something in your OS configuration? I have never experienced this phenomenon.

Comment: I've just checked on PC with Win7 and second one with WinXP. Both beep when shortcut is pressed (valid or invalid, doesn't matter).

Comment: There is a [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089986) about it. I still can't reproduce it, but I'm on Linux, so perhaps it's a Windows only thing.

Comment: @Itai, that bug you mention appears to have been recently (2019-05-20) fixed for openjfx13!